# How much phone data used for App connecting to cloud

Tags: android, bluetooth, smartphone

I want to build an android app that reads a smart watch (connected via Bluetooth) and sends the data it receives to a cloud or Google file.

I'm worried about how much smartphone data this will eat from the user's smartphone.

Is there a way to check how much data will be eaten up from the users' smartphones.

The app will be updating the cloud once every minute.

Answer (score 1):

You might try start your android app in emulator on desktop computer and meter his consumption.

Here's the walk through for NetBalancerapp that measures applications consumption:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43713/how-to-monitor-the-bandwidth-consumption-of-individual-applications/